# Opening the unused port & system call open("/dev/tty", ...) writev(7, [{"*** glibc detected *** ", 23}

Tags: glibc, tty

I am using a Linux platform (3.12.13 & 2.6.35.3),& imx5x series processor.
In my program I am using the two serial port for read write operation /dev/ttymxc2 & /dev/ttymxc1 .After some duration the /dev/tty open system call executes which is not a part of my program & the error comes  open("/dev/tty", ...) writev(7, [{"*** glibc detected *** ", 23}.

Please suggest some solution ,the port which i am not using in my code still system call executed to open /dev/tty/ .

These are some strace log .

```
open("/dev/ttymxc2", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 4
nanosleep({0, 200000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TCFLSH, 0x2)                   = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_START or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_TREAD or TCSETS, {B9600 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
open("/dev/ttymxc0", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 5
ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B115200 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_TREAD or TCSETS, {B115200 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
open("/dev/ttymxc1", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 6
nanosleep({0, 200000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(6, TCFLSH, 0x2)                   = 0
ioctl(6, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(6, SNDCTL_TMR_START or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_TREAD or TCSETS, {B9600 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76f2d000
write(1, "in main \n", 9)               = 9
write(1, " Leaving process fun \n", 22) = 22
sigreturn() (mask [])                   = 71
write(1, "bab0  bab0\n", 11)            = 11

open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 7

writev(7, [{"*** glibc detected *** ", 23}, {"./test11_2", 10}, {": ", 2}, {"double free or corruption (!prev"..., 33}, {": 0x", 4}, {"00bfa0c0", 8}, {" ***\n", 5}], 7) = 85

mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x76d2d000
munmap(0x76d2d000, 864256)              = 0
munmap(0x76f00000, 184320)              = 0
mprotect(0x76e00000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "final out", 9)                = 9
gettid()                                = 8796
tgkill(8796, 8796, SIGABRT)             = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=8796, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT +++
```

Comment: You're ignoring the important part of the error message: `writev(7, [{"*** glibc detected *** ", 23}, {"./test11_2", 10}, {": ", 2}, {"` **double free or corruption** . Your program has a serious bug in it; it either frees the same memory twice or has otherwise corrupted memory. Fix that and the message will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggest some solution

You need to fix the heap corruption bug that glibc discovered for you.

One way to do that is to run your program under Valgrind, but I don't believe it's available for `imx5x`.

Another way is to run the program with `export MALLOC_CHECK_=2`. See [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html).

Yet another way is to use [AddressSanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) (if your toolchain supports it).